# Auto start up midori browser is not working on Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to start browser in Raspberry Pi, on boot. These are the steps I've followed so far:

1. I have edited the `.bashrc` file from the root folder using this command:

> sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc

2. Added the following line at the end the file.

> midori -e Fullscreen -a http://www.google.com

3. I restarted Raspberry Pi.

> sudo reboot

It does not open the browser, on boot. How ever if I manually click on Terminal, it opens the browser.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask this question on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution .

In new versions it is not  supporting in this autostart file

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

I changed the code to the below autostart file.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Answer (score 3):

I got a very simple solution of this. At first install midori on your pi.

`sudo apt-get install midori`

Then add the file that you want to auto start here.

`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

For example you want to open google browser after reboot. Add this line to autostart file.

`@midori -e Fullscreen -a http://google.com`

Save the file and reboot your Pi. Now the google browser will auto start up every time you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add

```
@reboot command_you_want_to_run &
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using autostart of LXDE-pi and a sh file.

I had to install **xautomation** for simulate an user input

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

In the home of pi I've created a sh file

```
touch start_browser.sh
```

I've inserted the following code in the file

```
#!/bin/sh

# running the browser on the main desktop
sudo -u pi epiphany-browser -a --profile ~/.config http://www.google.com/ --display=:0 & 
# waits a few seconds, we wait that the browser has started successfully   
sleep 15s;
# xautomation simulates the pressure on the F11 key for activate the browser in full screen mode on the main desktop
xte "key F11" -x:0
```

I added the executable permission on the sh file with chmod command

```
sudo chmod 755 start_browser.sh
```

I've modified the autostart files of LXDE-pi session

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

by adding the following command to run my sh file

```
@/home/pi/start_browser.sh
```

Now our browser should be start in full screen mode at each boot

If it does not, check that the Raspberry's configuration had enabled the boot into the desktop environment

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select: *3 Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch*

Select: *Desktop Log in as user 'pi' at the graphical desktop*

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of raspberian you have to edit

```
sudo vi .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

for this

```
@midori -e Fullscreen -a http://google.com
```

to work..